# rviz to plot a plane with known (x,y,z) points

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have a list of (x,y,z) points all of which lie on the same plane. I need to visualize this plane on rviz with these points.

I googled on how to make a plane on rviz and someone mentioned making a cube but reduce a dimension so that it becomes a plane. Now, for a cube, we give a point which will become its center. But I have a bunch of (x,y,z) points that I need to visualize as a plane in rviz. How do I go about doing this? Any thoughts would be welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274918/rviz-to-plot-a-plane-with-known-(x,y,z)-points/) by [robot_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29498/robot_commander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The other answers contain some good pointers, but I would recommend you try out [davetcoleman/rviz_visual_tools](https://github.com/davetcoleman/rviz_visual_tools). It already provides you with the infrastructure to get RViz to render planes (in addition to all sorts of other geometric shapes).

[image: rviz visual tools].

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robot_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29498/robot_commander/) on 2017-11-06**:
oh wow. this is great! I'll check it out, thank you!

**Comment by [robot_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29498/robot_commander/) on 2017-11-06**:
I found [this git repo](https://github.com/DavidB-CMU/rviz_tools_py) which builds on [davetcoleman/rviz_visual_tools](https://github.com/davetcoleman/rviz_visual_tools) and gives me a python implementation of publishing markers.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-06**:
The Python lib is a good find, but notice that the last commit was already almost 2 years ago. `rviz_visual_tools` has seen some development since that time, so you might want to check whether the Python lib is missing something.

**Comment by [robot_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29498/robot_commander/) on 2017-11-06**:
ahhhh. I see. ok I'll look at it. Thank you very much for all your help! :)

Comment: Does this remain the tool of choice for ROS Noetic in 2023? Primarily, I need to visualize **many** polygons somewhat efficiently and conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest to use the [TriangleList](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Triangle_List_.28TRIANGLE_LIST.3D11.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D) as MarkerType. Do you have a triangulation of your points?

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robot_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29498/robot_commander/) on 2017-11-04**:
oh you mean, like to make a triangle with three points and increase the scale to visualize?

**Comment by [robot_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29498/robot_commander/) on 2017-11-04**:
ok so I tried making it a triangle and increasing the scale. Now I'm curious as to how the scale affects the triangle_list marker type. so what does scale.x, scale.y and scale.z do specifically in triangle_list marker type?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I'm concerned, it will be better to compute the plane's normal vector and center first by the list of points you mentioned. Then you can make a two-dimensional cube with normal vector and center like the way you have googled.

---

Originally posted by [jinseoi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32501/jinseoi/) with karma: 21 on 2017-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1